# How to save video playing currentTime in Laravel using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, laravel

This is my route which shows the lesson.

```
Route::get('/lession_video/{lession_id}','FrontendCommonController@lession_video')->name('lession_video');
```

Here is my another route which I am using for saving video currentTime in the database using ajax

```
Route::post('/saveTime/{video}', 'InstructorCourseController@saveTime')->name('video.saveTime');
```

This is one method which I am using for updating the video currentTime in database

```js
public function saveTime(Request $request, $lession_id){

    $user = Auth::user();
    if($user === null){
        return response()->json(['message' => 'User not authenticated', 404]);
    }

    $video = \App\Lession::where('id',$lession_id)->first();

    $currentTime = $request->time;
    $duration = $request->duration;
      // return $duration;
    //save them somewhere

    $watch_history = $user->watch_history;
    $watch_history_array = array();
    if ($watch_history == '') {
      array_push($watch_history_array, array('lesson_id' => $lession_id, 'progress' => $currentTime));
    } else {
      $founder = false;
      $watch_history_array = json_decode($watch_history, true);
      for ($i = 0; $i < count($watch_history_array); $i++) {
        $watch_history_for_each_lesson = $watch_history_array[$i];
        if ($watch_history_for_each_lesson['lesson_id'] == $video->id) {
          $watch_history_for_each_lesson['progress'] = $currentTime;
          // $watch_history_array[$i]['progress'] = $progress;
          $founder = true;
        }
      }
      if (!$founder) {
      array_push($watch_history_array, array('lesson_id' => $video->id, 'progress' => $currentTime));
      }
    }
    // return $watch_history_array;
    $data['watch_history'] = json_encode($watch_history_array);
    
    $check = User::where('id',$user->id)->update(['watch_history' => $watch_history_array]);

    return response()->json(['message' => 'Time saved', 200]);//send http response as json back to the ajax call

}
```

Next, this is my video player on course_video.blade.php file

```html
<video id="player" poster="/public/images/{{$lession->thumbnail}}" class="plyr">
  <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{csrf_token()}}" />
  <source src="/public/images/{{$lession->resource}}" />
</video>
```

Then next on the same Blade page I have my ajax code as follows

```js
<script>
  var vid = document.getElementById("player");

  $(function() {
    var timeout;

    $("#player").on("playing pause", function(e) {
      // save reference
      var v = this;

      // clear previous timeout, if any
      clearTimeout(timeout);

      // call immediately if paused or when started
      performaction(v.currentTime, v.duration);

      // set up interval to fire very 5 seconds
      if (e.type === "playing") {
        timeout = setInterval(function() {
          performaction(v.currentTime, v.duration);
        }, 1000);
      }
    });

    function performaction(currentTime, duration, lession_id) {
      //pass video id to this function where you call it.
      var data = { time: currentTime, duration: duration }; //data to send to server
      var dataType = "json"; //expected datatype from server
      var headers = { "X-CSRF-TOKEN": $('input[name="_token"]').val() };
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '{{route("video.saveTime",$lession_id)}}', //url of the server which stores time data
        data: data,
        headers: headers,
        success: function(data, status) {
          alert(status);
          var data = JSON.parse(data);
          alert(data["message"]);
        },
        dataType: dataType
      });
    }
  });
</script>
```

I want to store this currentTime in the database but this code is not working and even I didn't get it how the route for savetime and its method savetime() gets executed.